# JavaFX: FXML component loading in new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, fxml

I am developing JavaFX desktop application with some FXML. However I have to actually change the view on the run so I will load FXML several times (and also to change the used language setting) so I started to think if it is possible load FXML components in different thread. I have come up with this:

```
   new Thread(() -> {
        Node n;
        try {
            n = (Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                root.getChildren().add(n);                 
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }}).start();
```

New thread loads the components and the Platform than sends it to Application thread.

Is it safe or is there some problem that I have skipped? Would it be overkill to to use it everywhere?

Comment: This really shouldn't be necessary. Unless you are doing something very unusual (like loading the FXML from a remote location), FXML loading is going to be very fast and need not be done in a background thread. If your controller takes time to initialize (e.g. it's getting data from a database, etc), then the controller should manage the threading for that part.

Comment: So it is a bit overkill.